# data Overlapping in crystal reports

Tags: c#

I have created around 9 crystal reports today and I noticed a problem in all the reports. Below is the link for the design of my report. I am not using any SP or View , just loading the gridview data by using a dataset.Now when I click on Print button in the front end..if the records are less than like 10 all of them are displayed in the first page but the summary in the second page is overlapped with the details as shown below link

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=164068347074025&set=a.164065450407648.38272.100004125821604&type=3&theater

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=164068363740690&set=a.164065450407648.38272.100004125821604&type=3&theater

Please help me with the below queries 1) Why the Page header and Details layout are displayed in the second page even when there are no records. 2) Why the Report footer is getting overlapped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Why the Page header and Details layout are displayed in the second page even when there are no records.

as per you choose page size , the content of your data will made this thing. second chance is in your design , you may be given more space horizontally between header, section , footer.

2) Why the Report footer is getting overlapped?

for this set properties(print at bottom) true in section expert(where section name written right click of any section )

http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.in/2008/09/how-to-handle-overlapping-of-large-text.html